# Как засунуть все данные об inline кнопках в один параметр?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Делаю тг бота и хочу чтобы он отправлял сообщения с инлайн кнопками в разные чаты, но консоль выдаёт ошибку 404 not found

```
def main(chat_id="-788513201",  keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(), url_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Перейти на опрос",url="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1")):
    resp = requests.get(url="https://api.telegram.org/bot***", data=dict(chat_id=chat_id, keyboard=keyboard, url_button=url_button))
    keyboard.add(url_button)
    print(resp.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Какой ты запрос к API выполняешь? после *[https://api.telegram.org/bot[token]/](https://api.telegram.org/bot%5Btoken%5D/)* должно быть название метода, например sendMessage и там уже указываешь все параметры. Вообще лучше почитай документацию или используй готовые библиотеки (например, pyTelegramBotAPI), так будет проще.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: А можно пример как после метода писать параметры?

Comment: /sendMessage?chat_id=123456789&text=Hello,%20world! Если писать в таком формате - пишет 404 not found